# uniform convergence on compacts in probability is preserved under continuous transformation

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, continuity, stochastic-processes, uniform-convergence

Suppose we have a sequence of $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued stochastic processes $(X^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ **converging to $X$ uniformly on compacts in probability**, i.e.
$$
\operatorname{plim}_{n \to \infty} \sup\limits_{s \in [0,N]} ||X_s^n - X_s||_{\mathbb{R}^d} = 0 \;\; \forall N \in \mathbb{N},
$$
where plim denotes convergence in probability. Equivalently we could write that for all $t \geq 0, \varepsilon > 0$
$$
\mathbb{P}[\sup_{s\leq t}||X^n_s-X_s||_{\mathbb{R}^d}>\varepsilon]\to 0.
$$

> I now want to know whether the ucp-convergence in probability is preserved under continuous transformations, i.e. if $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is continuous, then $f(X^n)$ converges ucp  to $f(X)$ in probability.

I have the intuition that this statements holds (since we are looking at compact sets, the function is even uniformly continuous and hence doesn't explode too much), but I am not able to show it. I have already thought about the more specific case of **Lipschitz-continuity**. For this type of continuity I can show that the statement holds, because for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that
$$
\sup_{s \in [0,N]}||f(X^n_s)-f(X_s)||_{\mathbb{R}^k} \leq L \sup_{s \in [0,N]}||X^n_s-X_s||_{\mathbb{R}^d} \to L *0 = 0,
$$
where $L>0$ is $f$'s Lipschitz-constant, hence the limit in propability can be estimated from above by $0$.
Turning to the more general case, I thought about applying the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criteria. Since I am looking at compact intervals of the form $[0,N]$, I know that $f$ is uniformly continuous there.
Hence given a $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta_\varepsilon > 0$ such that
$$
|| X^n_s - X_s  ||_{\mathbb{R}^d} < \delta_\varepsilon \implies || f(X^n_s) - f(X_s) ||_{\mathbb{R}^k} < \varepsilon 
$$
for $s \in [0,N], N \in \mathbb{N}$. Now I don't know hot to go on. Does the statement even hold? If no, is there a nice counterexample?

Comment: It is preserved under uniformly continuous $f$. This is an  easy consequence of the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: But how does the definition exactly play out in the context? Was my $\epsilon-\delta$-Ansatz right? How does it go on? Thanks in advance.